# How to send two tuples as arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, tuples, typedef

Hello i am new to C++ and im trying to make a program that takes two complex numbers, sumarizes them and return the sum.

What i am planning to do is sending two tuples into a function and returning one tuple.

```
typedef tuple<float, float> complex_tuple;
  complex_tuple a_tuple(a, b);
  complex_tuple b_tuple(c, d);


    cout << sum(a_tuple, b_tuple);
```

and this is my function:

```
tuple<float,float> sum(tuple<float, float>a, tuple<float, float>b){
  float a_real= get<0>(a);
  float a_imag= get<1>(a);
  float b_real= get<0>(b);
  float b_imag= get<1>(b);
  return tuple<float, float>(a_real+b_real, a_imag+b_imag);
}
```

the error i get is:

```
0.cc:28:31: Error: no match for "operator<<" in "std::cout << sum(std::tuple<float, float>, std::tuple<float, float>)(b_tuple)"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the iostream stuff doesn't support the tuple type.

Comment: I hope you know that complex numbers are already part of C++'s standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to say that you want to print the sum to `cout`, but `cout` doesn't know how to handle values of type `complex_tuple`.

Provide an overload of `operator<<(ostream&, const complex_tuple&)` to allow the code to compile:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const complex_tuple& tuple) {
    os << get<0>(tuple) << "+" << get<1>(tuple) << "i";
    return os;
}
```

[Further information](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/).

Comment: Thank you, kind sir! This works even better than the previous solution. I had no idea I was able to manipulate the ostream like that!

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that an overload for `std::cout` and `operator<<(std::tuple)` exists is wrong. The error message is pretty clear on that.

You'll need to print the elements of the tuple separately.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `operator<<`. There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted except you haven't written this function yet.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const complex_tuple& x);
```

Write that function and the error will go away.